# How to give two functions to delegate function

Tags: javascript, jquery, delegates, jquery-events

I'm using JQuery and trying to use `delegate` for the `hover` action. Problem is the hover action can get two handlers, the handle in and the handle out. How can I achieve this using delegate?

I've tried this and it didn't work:

```
 $(document).delegate('.box', 'hover',  
    function() { $(".a").addClass(".hover");}, 
    function() { $(".a").removeClass(".hover");});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the docs for [`.hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/):

```
$(selector).mouseenter(handlerIn).mouseleave(handlerOut);
```

So you should be able to just call `delegate` once for each of these functions:

```
$(document)
  .delegate('.box', 'mouseenter', function() { alert(1); })
  .delegate('.box', 'mouseleave', function() { alert(2); });
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to [@Justin's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733233/how-to-give-two-functions-to-delegate-function/6733265#6733265) is to check the event type in the callback:

```
function onMouseenter()
{
    alert(1);
}
function onMouseleave()
{
    alert(2);
}

$(document).delegate('.box', 'hover', function(event)
{
    if (event.type === 'mouseenter') onMouseenter.apply(this, arguments);
    else onMouseleave.apply(this, arguments);
});
```

That said, it's unnecessary to use `.delegate()` if you're just going to delegate to `document`. Use `.live()` instead, which is much more concise:

```
$('.box').live('hover', function (event)
{
    // snip...
});
```